# Mocking a static method with a generic parameter

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I have the following setup :

Class to test : `SeriesOffset` which extends `BaseDisplayOption`

Test Class : `SeriesOffsetTest`

When creating an object of the `SeriesOffset` class to test it, the constructor of the same makes a super call which then makes the following method call :

```
 logger = LoggingService.getLog(this.getClass());
```

where `LoggingService` is an abstract class and `getLog(Class<?> clazz)` is a static method with a generic class parameter. This very method call needs to be mocked. I created a mock implementation for the same with a class called `ILogImpl` and this is how I am trying to test it:

```
    ILogImpl a = new ILogImpl();
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(LoggingService.class);
    PowerMockito.when(LoggingService.getLog( SeriesOffset.class)).thenReturn(a);
```

But this method doesnt seem to work and it calls the real implementation instead of the mock one that I need it to call.
The error trace is the following : [error trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTgVQ.png)

Comment: Have you added next lines for your test `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` 
`@PrepareForTest(LoggingService.class)`?

Comment: What is the code of LoggingService?

Comment: @Crazyjavahacking http://pastebin.com/FjeVpuwR

Comment: @EugenMartynov Yes I have

Answer (score 0):

According to the error trace, I don't see where your real implementation of `getLog` is being called—but the real class initializer ("clinit") *is* being called as part of mock creation, because you're at least referring to the actual class and its static fields and `static {}` blocks are being loaded as usual.

Look to line 41 of LoggingService.java, and if the problem isn't obvious there, edit your answer so we can see it and diagnose further.